# How to proper interstitial ad implementationin android?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a sticker app and I want the interstitial ads to appear right after pressing the add button and the action happens. The problem is that the ad only appears a few times. I think it's due to implementation. Could someone analyze the code and tell you where I can put it to work properly?

```
protected void addStickerPackToWhatsApp(String identifier, String stickerPackName) {
    try {
        //if neither WhatsApp Consumer or WhatsApp Business is installed, then tell user to install the apps.
        if (!WhitelistCheck.isWhatsAppConsumerAppInstalled(getPackageManager()) && !WhitelistCheck.isWhatsAppSmbAppInstalled(getPackageManager())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        final boolean stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppConsumer = WhitelistCheck.isStickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppConsumer(this, identifier);
        final boolean stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppSmb = WhitelistCheck.isStickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppSmb(this, identifier);
        if (!stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppConsumer && !stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppSmb) {
            //ask users which app to add the pack to.
            launchIntentToAddPackToChooser(identifier, stickerPackName);
        } else if (!stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppConsumer) {
            launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(identifier, stickerPackName, WhitelistCheck.CONSUMER_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME);
        } else if (!stickerPackWhitelistedInWhatsAppSmb) {
            launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(identifier, stickerPackName, WhitelistCheck.SMB_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error adding sticker pack to WhatsApp",  e);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private void launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(String identifier, String stickerPackName, String whatsappPackageName) {
    Intent intent = createIntentToAddStickerPack(identifier, stickerPackName);
    intent.setPackage(whatsappPackageName);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_PACK);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//Handle cases either of WhatsApp are set as default app to handle this intent. We still want users to see both options.
private void launchIntentToAddPackToChooser(String identifier, String stickerPackName) {
    Intent intent = createIntentToAddStickerPack(identifier, stickerPackName);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.add_to_whatsapp)), ADD_PACK);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@NonNull
private Intent createIntentToAddStickerPack(String identifier, String stickerPackName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.whatsapp.intent.action.ENABLE_STICKER_PACK");
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, identifier);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY, BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME, stickerPackName);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("my-ad-unit-id");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });

    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == ADD_PACK) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (data != null) {
                final String validationError = data.getStringExtra("validation_error");
                if (validationError != null) {
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        //validation error should be shown to developer only, not users.
                        MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_validation_error, validationError).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "validation error");
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "Validation failed:" + validationError);
                }
            } else {
                new StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sticker_pack_not_added");
            }
        }
        if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

}

public static final class StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> dismiss())
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_play_link, (dialog, which) -> launchWhatsAppPlayStorePage());

        return dialogBuilder.create();
    }

    private void launchWhatsAppPlayStorePage() {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            final boolean whatsAppInstalled = WhitelistCheck.isPackageInstalled(WhitelistCheck.CONSUMER_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME, packageManager);
            final boolean smbAppInstalled = WhitelistCheck.isPackageInstalled(WhitelistCheck.SMB_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME, packageManager);
            final String playPackageLinkPrefix = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
            if (whatsAppInstalled && smbAppInstalled) {
                launchPlayStoreWithUri("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=WhatsApp+Inc.");
            } else if (whatsAppInstalled) {
                launchPlayStoreWithUri(playPackageLinkPrefix + WhitelistCheck.CONSUMER_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME);
            } else if (smbAppInstalled) {
                launchPlayStoreWithUri(playPackageLinkPrefix + WhitelistCheck.SMB_WHATSAPP_PACKAGE_NAME);
            }
        }
    }

    private void launchPlayStoreWithUri(String uriString) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uriString));
        intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.cannot_find_play_store, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I added the ads to loading in the intent, because when click on the add buttons it calls the intent, and then I put them to display the ads after executing action through an if

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, ad appearing only a few times is because Google Admob doesn't give 100% fill rate to the ads.

There is also the number of times a user can see an ad in the app. Setting these limits prevents misuse of ads from user as well as by developer.

1. If you're able to show unlimited ads to users, it'll lead to developers spamming users with only ads degrading user experience.
2. If users are able to see unlimited ads, one user will watch boat-load of ads in a day, increasing your revenue, meaning, there'll be more chances of fraud clicks as well as fraud impressions.
3. You're able to get 100% ad fill rate, in case you're a big app developer, as more people will bid to get ads on your app, meaning more fill rate.
4. Anyways, if you still decide to bombard users with ads, you can use **ad mediation platforms**, Google Admob has one too, to fetch ads from various Ad platforms to **increase your fill rate**.

Answer (score 2):

Admob having very poor in providing ads, they have lower fill rates. So I suggest you to add other ads networks too if one of network is failed to provide ads.(E.g. Facebook, StartApp, AppLovin etc.)